# Question on using "," in non compound sentences

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Kindly consider below sentence :

> We are bound by the laws, not by the intent of our legislators.

I've read that a "," is used when joining two clauses. So when I look at above sentence my first feel is it can be a compound sentence.  But the phrase after "," has no subject or verb, so it must be just a prepositional phrase. May I know *why they are using "," when it is clearly not a compound sentence ?*

Comment: Back in the 60s we all carried placards saying [***Make Love not War***.](https://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB807GB807&biw=1344&bih=868&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=_oJgW_SZKYmFgAadv4nICw&q=placards+slogans+%22make+love+not+war%22&oq=placards+slogans+%22make+love+not+war%22&gs_l=img.3...32331.43341.0.44262.26.25.1.0.0.0.84.1435.25.25.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.0.0....0.g2rI75DRr3Q) But I don't remember anyone agonising over whether to include a comma, or why they might not (syntactically) *need* to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a form of coordination, where two different deletions are permitted. The underlying sentence is something like

> We are bound by the laws, and we are not bound by the intent of our legislators.

(I'm not saying that anybody would say that; but that is the full logical form)

The repeated part can often be deleted in a coordination:

> We are bound by the laws, and not by the intent of our legislators.

Finally, the coordinator *and* can often be dropped when it is directly followed by *not*. (Alternatively, you could regard *not* as a coordinator in its own right). This gives

> We are bound by the laws, not by the intent of our legislators.

So the structure is that the second "by" clause is a parallel indirect object of the VP "We are bound".

As for the comma, I would regard it as optional in all of these; but I would put it in, because in speaking them I would take a new breath group for "not ... ". As far as I am concerned, most of the "rules" for using commas are arbitrary nonsense: the rule I prefer is "When you take a new breath group, write a comma or other punctuation".